# Render Form inside Yii2 Gui Tab

Tags: yii2

My application have to have multiple language, so I decided to separate each language by using tab (Yii2 gui), but how can I render the form in side the 'content' key?

```
<?php 
$language_tab=[];
$increment=0;

$content="I love you";
 foreach($language as $obj){
    $language_tab[$increment] = array('label' => $obj->name ,'content' => $content);    
    $increment++;
 }
echo Tabs::widget([

    'items' => $language_tab,
    'options' => ['tag' => 'div'],
    'itemOptions' => ['tag' => 'div'],
    'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'my-class'],
    'clientOptions' => ['collapsible' => false],
]);
?>

<div class="status-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'date_created')->textInput() ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

I just wanna change from $content to the form below.
Please help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create separate view for the form and render it:

```
...
'content' => $this->render('_language_form', ['language' => $obj, 'model' => $model]), 
...
```

Comment: Thanks so much it's working perfectly ,but I have one more question , how can I save my "status-form" in multiple language at the same time?

Comment: Handling multiple models submission has a special topic in wiki - http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/666/handling-tabular-data-loading-and-validation-in-yii-2/  One more thing here is that you have to place your Tabs widget inside form tags - so that all its content would be sent by one button click.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment. Now I know how to do it. Really Really Thanks you